# How to Insert text in existing pdf using PRAWN gem in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn

I am working on 1 application and trying to open and edit pdf using rails PRAWN gem,

i have tried some ways like

```
@id1 = "Name"
@id2 = "age"
@id3 = "birthday"

Prawn::Document.generate "/home/test.pdf" do |@fname|
  data = [["#{@id1} | #{@id2} | #{@id3}"], ["Address", "Country"]]
  {:border_width => 0}.each do |property, value|
    @fname.table(data, :column_widths => [470, 70, 100], :cell_style => {property => value})
  end
  @fname.stroke_horizontal_rule
  @fname.move_down(20)
end
send_file("/home/test.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
```

it is adding content but the contents are overlapping on the existing content

Is there anyone who can help me to insert content at to top of the first page without overlapping that content on the existing one

The existing content should shift down.

Ideas other then PRAWN are also invited.

Comment: This is not possible. There is no "text flow" in PDF, just statically positioned elements. You would have to manually move all other elements.

Comment: Yeah you are right but how can i move other element manually in my code

Comment: Sorry i don't know prawn, my comment just applied to PDF in general.